# how do i display the process of this code

Tags: c

I have a question, how do i display the process of this code

```
// sum of numbers from 1 to 100
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    sum = sum + i;
}
printf("%d", sum);
```

the code above will print sum of the numbers from 1 to 100

and i want to display or print the 1+2+3+4+5...+100

I have tried

```
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        sum = sum + i;
        printf("Result = %d + %d\n", sum , i);
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
```

Comment: *progess.......

Answer (score 0):

You need to print just the current value of `i` each time through the loop.

You need to treat the last iteration specially, since it shouldn't be followed by `+`.

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    sum += i;
    printf("%d ", i);
    if (i < 100) {
        printf("+ ", i);
    }
}

printf("= %d\n", sum);
```